# iPhone iOS how to save/serialize UIView on the screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, serialization, uiview

I have an interface designed in the interface builder it has a whole bunch of little elements, whose position I would like to remember, because the user can re-arrange the interface using gestures. I'm hoping that the user would be able **to save the UI customization** and re-open it next time the app is running.

**How can I go about remembering the position of a particular UI element (ex: `center.x`, `center.y`, transforms for `scale` and `rotation`?**

Currently I have a `NSMutableDictionary` in place with ~16 elements, but the total number of parameters that I need to save is close to 50. Is there a way for me to simplify the task, without having to define 50 dictionary key/value pairs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIView conforms to NSCoding so you can save it directly to a NSKeyedArchive.

If you've added your own properties on top of the normal UIView you'll have to make sure your class can handle NSCoding.  If the properties are standard framework types it's likely they already support it.

If you go to any documentation page, you'll see a "Conforms to" section at the top - look for NSCoding.